# Nhibernate Conformist Mapping "Unable to determine type..."

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

The class:

```
    public class SOPProcess : ISOPProcess
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual SOP SOP { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcessType Type { get; set; }       

    public virtual SOPProcessInput Input { get; set; }
    public virtual SOPProcessOutput Output { get; set; }
    public virtual SOPProcessMeasures Measures { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal YieldFactor { get; set; }

    public virtual SOPProcess PreviousProcess { get; set; }
    public virtual SOPProcess NextProcess { get; set; }
}
```

The Mapping:

```
public class SOPProcessMap : ClassMapping<SOPProcess>
{
    public SOPProcessMap()
    {
        Id(s => s.Id, i => i.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));

        Property(s => s.YieldFactor);           

        ManyToOne(s => s.SOP, m =>
                                {
                                    m.Column("SopId");
                                    m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                                });

        ManyToOne(s => s.Type, m =>
                                {
                                    m.Column("ProcessTypeId");
                                    m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                                });

        ManyToOne(s => s.NextProcess, m =>
                                        {
                                            m.Column("NextProcessId");
                                            m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                                        });

        ManyToOne(s => s.PreviousProcess, m =>
                                            {
                                                m.Column("PreviousProcessId");
                                                m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                                            });
    }
}
```

The Error:

> NHibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: MES.ProcessManager.SOP.SOPProcess, MES.ProcessManager, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(id)

I hope it's something simple, this is my first project using the Conformist mapping, so maybe I'm just overlooking something.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From our discussion on the nhusers mailing list.

I ran across the same problems.

You haven't defined the type of relationship. See the line action => action.OneToMany()); in the mapping below.

```
public class SportMap : ClassMapping<Sport>
{
    public SportMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Column("Id");
            map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
        });

        Property(x => x.Name, map =>
        {
            map.NotNullable(true);
            map.Length(50);
        });

        Bag(x => x.Positions, map =>
        {
            map.Key(k => k.Column(col => col.Name("SportId")));
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
        },
        action => action.OneToMany());

        Property(x => x.CreateDate);
        Property(x => x.CreateUser);
        Property(x => x.LastUpdateDate);
        Property(x => x.LastUpdateUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I encountered this same problem when switching from using a `ConventionModelMapper` to a `ModelMapper`, this led me to the answer. The `SimpleModelInspector` figures out the action to use for each collection.

Comment: Same here. Thanks for sharing, the error message is rather enigmatic.

Comment: So looking at @Fran's and tom.dietrich's notes, an action must be supplied for both "Bag()" and "Set()" methods.  Wondering under what conditions it's allowable/useful to leave this (apparently optional) param off; if none, should be required, forcing investigation/reducing incidents of the exception altogether.

Comment: @user1172173 It's not optional.

Comment: Actually it is optional, but sry shoulda been clearer (broke my own rule!).  The "Set()" method is overloaded w/ a ver that excludes this param so in essence, relationship  is not "required" to register a set mapping.  Was wondering when it would be useful/non-trivial to do this (i.e. not know the relationship) - or even valid, esp when it's failing on this element during overall config collection validation (that part may be a bug).  If no clear intent, seems there should only be the one "Set()" impl that requires the relationship.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that the problem was in my Set mappings in other classes. If you don't specify the action for the mapping, it throws this (misleading) error.